# Creating Async Observable from array in a service and outputing to template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs

I am building a geolocation app, as users login their location is added and they get added to the array "nearme" by way of their details and coords being pushed into it from Firebase. The desired result is that this array will be turned into an observable which I can output in the components html but I seem to be doing something wrong as nothing is passing into it. Its obviously something wrong with how I am accessing the array in outputUsers()  but I cant figure out what the problem is or how to make this array async in the component for realtime updates on users that are close by.. any help much appreciated.

```
    import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
    import { Geolocation, Geoposition, BackgroundGeolocation } from 'ionic-native';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
    import { Fb } from './firebase';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
    import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    export class Iusers {
    userid: string;
    userdistance: string;
    userloc: string;
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class LocationTracker {

        public usersNearMe$: Observable<Iusers[]>;
        private _usersNearMeObserver: Observer<Iusers[]>;
        private _usersNearMeDataStore: { users: Iusers[] };

        public nearme = <[Iusers]>[];

    constructor(public zone: NgZone, public fire:Fb ) {
            this.usersNearMe$ = new Observable<Iusers[]>(observer => this._usersNearMeObserver = observer).share();                 
            this._usersNearMeDataStore = {  users: [] };
    }



    startTracking( activeUser:any ) :any  {
        ... other stuff going on here .....

        geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
            this.nearme.push({ userid: key, userloc: location, userdistance: distance.toFixed(2) });
        });
    }



    outputUsers() {
    this._usersNearMeDataStore.users = this.nearme;
    this._usersNearMeObserver.next(this._usersNearMeDataStore.users);
    }





    }
```

The Component that displays this information once it receives it is laid out as follows:

```
        export class OverviewPage {

        public members: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
        public activeUser: string;
        public usersNearMe: Observable<any>;

        constructor(  public locationTracker: LocationTracker, public fire: Fb, af: AngularFire,  public appHeaderPopover:AppHeaderPopoverController, public zone: NgZone, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams ) {
                    this.locationTracker.startTracking( this.activeUser );  
                    this.locationTracker.usersNearMe$
                    this.locationTracker.outputUsers();
        }

  ... more stuff...

 }
```

and the html template

```
      <div class="" *ngFor="let item of usersNearMe | async">
        item {{ item.key }}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this._usersNearMeObserver.next(this._usersNearMeDataStore.users);` inside `outputUsers()` is the only place where you're publishing values from your observer. This code in only called once.

My guess is that you want to publish new values from inside the `startTracking()` method, since that's where you are fetching new values.

I don't know exactly what result you are trying to achieve, but adding `outputUsers()` here should publish values whenever you track changes:

```
geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
    this.nearme.push({ userid: key, userloc: location, userdistance: distance.toFixed(2) });
    this.outputUsers();
});
```